# How To make Mysql Forginkeys?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have many tables like users table, users_token, articles, comments,and so on,
and in this table, there is a user_id field in table, should I make foreign keys on users table ?

**users**
`id  int (11) primary_key auto_increment,and so on`

**articles**
`id 
user_id`

**comments**
`id
user_id`

should I make 2 or more foreign keys to users table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should create foreign key constraints. They protect you from inconsistent data.

Imagine you have a user with id 1, and an article that references that user via its `user_id` field. Then, for some reason, user 1 is deleted from the `user` table. Now you have an article that has a reference to a non-existing record. It could get worse: now imagine a new user record is inserted with an explicitly mentioned id: 1. Now the article references a user that really is not the user it originally referred to.

These and other inconsistency problems can be circumvented by foreign key constraints.

Comment: But I means that : so many tables has references to users table , so that i should many fk on my users tables . I don`t know it`s right or bad .